# Understanding PHP Classes

Tags: php, object, built-in

I am trying to understand the built-in classes in PHP and how to use them. Also I am trying to use the correct language to describe these 'things'. Take for example the DateTime class.

So now I see a method on this class and it is denoted by DateTime::setDate . So am I correct in saying, "this is the DateTime class that has a method called setDate ?  Also if you read the PHP manual on the DateTime class for setDate you find:

DateTime::setDate   <-- does this mean I can use this as is in code? As in:
DateTime::setDate();  ?

I do see how to create an object as in the below:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(2001, 2, 3);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');// how would you know to do this? I thought $date->year;
?>
```

And this came from this:
public DateTime DateTime::setDate ( int $year , int $month , int $day )

Also from the line directly above I should be able to figure out how to use it without seeing an example?

Any good input would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Start by reading **all** this http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.php . Then, there is no magical way, the doc is there to tell you which methods / signatures are available for a class.

Comment: Just turn error reporting on, and try both. It will only take a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hate the `::` notation in reference, I always think I am dealing with a long static methods list.

Anyway it comes from [C++ namespaces notation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/), so `DateTime::diff` is meant to be read "the function `diff` belongs to class `DateTime`", but it seems quite clear because I am on the DateTime reference page!

To keep things clearer, the "double colon" operator is called `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` [hebrew for double colon actually].

Long story short, go with `->` notation unless you read the **static** keyword in the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a method is denoted as being `static`, you *cannot* invoke it in code with `classname::methodname();`.  In code descriptions, the `::` basically just says 'this method belongs to this class'.  Yeah, it's kinda confusing.

Comment: You and Moonwave tie. He answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I never understood why they use the `::` operator in the documentation and I find it confusing.

But when the documentation says `DateTime::setDate` it means that this is the method definition. You must first instantiate the class with:

```
$instance = new DateTime();
```

Then call the method on the instance:

```
$instance->setDate($dateString);
```

This is how methods work on class objects, and it is written as `Classe::method`.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP help you can find this expression: "Sometimes it is useful to refer to functions and variables in base classes or to refer to functions in classes that have not yet any instances. The :: operator is being used for this."
The :: operator used to call the function of base class and ignores classes that made from base class that overrides the method.

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am the original function A::example().<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am the redefined function B::example().<br />\n";
        A::example();
    }
}

// there is no object of class A.
// this will print
//   I am the original function A::example().<br />
A::example();

// create an object of class B.
$b = new B;

// this will print 
//   I am the redefined function B::example().<br />
//   I am the original function A::example().<br />
$b->example();
?>
```

Comment: And note that :: comes after class name (without $) not after variable (with $).

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method A::example() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\jims\abc.php on line 18  <--- But I get what you are doing here. Prefixing with static function does work.